# SPSS and Linear Mixed Models

Tags: self-study, spss

I hope you would be able to help me! I am working on a LMM in SPSS right now and I've gotten to the point where I don't really know what to do.

I am looking into comfort (so that is my DV, measured several times during the day) and factors I wanted to include in the model are: the two different scenarios (protocols) we've done, time of day. Now, BMI and the age of the participant has also been shown (in the literature) to affect comfort so I wanted to include those in the model as well. I know that in SPSS when I specify the covariates, those are variables that are continuous. But I wonder, what is the difference between leaving the variables only in the covariate box and also adding them in the random effects box? I've tried running the model twice -- once with only adding the variables in the covariates box and once after transfering them to the random effects box and it seems that the model is "better" (based on the AIC value) when I run it without adding age and BMI to the random variable box.

So it is either only this:

[image: So it is either this:]

Or I also add them in the Random effects box too: 
[image: Or:]

Seems that based on the AIC value the first model is better..

Answer (score 1):

Adding variables to the Covariates box in the main dialog actually doesn't include them in the model in any way. It only includes them in determining cases with complete data on all variables named in the procedure. In order for them to actually be used as predictors of any kind in the model, you have to specify them in either the Fixed, Random, or both dialogs. I'm not sure from this whether you also specified age and BMI in the fixed part of the model or not. If so, then adding them to the random part uses them as both fixed and random effects. If the AIC and other information criteria are better (smaller) when using them only as fixed effects (or leaving them out of the model entirely), then that recommends not using them as random effects, but if you have theoretical reasons for needing them as random effects, you may not want to simply blindly rely on the information criteria to decide.